# Improve Neo4j Cypher Query find synonyms on image board with gds.alpha.linkprediction.commonNeighbors

Tags: database, algorithm, neo4j, cypher, data-science

Hi i have the following query:

I have crawled and saved an imageboard into a neo4j database.
On this website users can ad "tags" to images, which can be used to search for them.

Because i want to help to improve the search i want to add the missing tags to the images.
My idea was to find Tags which are synonyms. Therefore i created a query which should help me to find tags which are very common together and therefore are most likely synonyms.

My query looks like this:

```
MATCH (tags1:Tag)-[:HasTag]-(:Post)-[:HasTag]-(tags2:Tag)
WHERE id(tags1) <> id(tags2)
AND  id(tags1) < id(tags2)
WITH gds.alpha.linkprediction.commonNeighbors(tags1, tags2) AS score,tags1,tags2
RETURN tags1.name,tags2.name,score
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Because i have 64 million nodes and 188 million relations the query takes very long.
Do you guys have some ideas how to improve the runtime of the query?
Maybe a totaly different query could help me even better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a very large graph, so any pair comparing queries will take a long time. What I've seen some people do is to calculate node embeddings with FastRP algorithm, and then use kNN to find the most similar nodes. You could define a high similarityCutoff threshold, which would then hopefully find relationships between similar or identical tags.